# Intersection of an infinite sequence of open dense sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{G_n\}$ be a sequence of infinite open dense subsets of a complete metric space $X$. I have already proved intersection of $\{G_n\}$ is non-empty and now wants to prove this intersection is dense in $X$ (as it's claimed to be correct in a textbook), but got no idea on how to do so.

Comment: What do you have available? Proving that from scratch is pretty hard

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I believe my answer is quite accessible to OP.

Comment: @geetha290krm That is pretty smooth

Answer (score 3):

If $U$ is a non-empty open set then $U$ is itself a complete metric space under an equivalent metric. Consider $U\cap G_n$ in this space to see that $\cap G_n$ intersects $U$. Hence, $\cap G_n$ is dense.

Ref.: [Open subsets of a complete metric space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219706/open-subsets-of-a-complete-metric-space)